# Need SSRS Expression for Percent of Change that avoids division by zero error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a field in my report that shows the percentage of difference between two other columns A and B. Columns A and B are integer values and can each be positive, negative, or zero. I need to be able to provide a positive, negative, or zero % change based on the difference between A and B.

I understand (and have used many times) the usual method as posted all over StackOverflow for avoiding division by zero error in SSRS:

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value=0,0,Fields!B.Value-Fields!A.Value/IIF(Fields!A.Value=0,1,Fields!A.Value))
```

However in this case the usual method is insufficient. Consider the following:

```
 A   |   B   |   Diff   |   % Change        |  % Change
                         (By Usual Method)   (As I need to see it)
 2   |   3   |    1     |     50%           |     50%
-1   |   2   |    3     |     -300%         |     300%
 0   |   0   |    0     |     0%            |     0%
 0   |   3   |    3     |     0%            |     100%
 0   |  -3   |   -3     |     0%            |    -100%
```

I need an expression that will avoid the divide by zero error, but I cannot simply replace the error message with 0%. Any help the community can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the % change you want to see, you'll need to do something slightly different whenever A=0 or A<0.  So, using your examples of A for original value and B for the new value: if A is 0 determine if your % change should be 0 or +/-100 based on the value of B.  If A is not 0, handle negative values of A by taking the absolute value in the denominator; otherwise use the normal % change formula:

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value=0, 
IIF(Fields!B.Value=0, 0, Fields!B.Value/Abs(Fields!B.Value)), 
IIF(Fields!A.Value<0, (Fields!B.Value-Fields!A.Value)/Abs(Fields!A.Value), (Fields!B.Value-Fields!A.Value)/Fields!A.Value))
```

Seems to work for your provided values and for a few others I made up:

[image: SSRS Example]

Answer (score 1):

How about a null? I am assuming you are stuck on using a format of "P0" the below will work but will not yield a "%" sign.

```
IIF(Fields!Denominator.Value=0 OR IsNothing(Fields!Denominator.Value),"",(Fields!Numerator.Value / Fields!Denominator.Value) * 100)
```

Comment: Could you just use Abs(D) / Abs(N) and show a -growth based on the values?

Comment: @Irb This does not speak to my orginal intent which was to find a solution that treats going from 0 to 30  (growth) differently than going from 0 to 0 (no growth). However formating div/0 errors to blank on my report is acceptable to my boss, and in the end that is what really matters! however the proposed formula is incomplete and will still cause div/0 errors because IIF does not short circut.

Comment: @Irb looks like we are working at the same time, sorry to have deleted the comment you were responding to!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Irb 's incomplete solution: This will provide a null value when demoninator is zero

```
=IIF(Fields!Denominator.Value=0,
Nothing,
Fields!Numerator.Value/IIF(Fields!Denominator.Value=0,1,Fields!Denominator.Value))
```